# asmx webservice receives null values from ksoap2 android

Tags: android, web-services, asmx, ksoap2

I'm connecting to .asmx webservice through andriod via ksoap2 but unfortunately web service receives null value as sent from android! 
I'm connecting to local IIS server (laptop), My server used be live everything was fine, since I've deployed my services on local machine its not receiving parameters from android!!

```
// URL = "http://192.168.#.#/"
// NAME_SPACE = "http://192.168.#.#/cabservice.asmx";

String webResult = null;
Resources resource = this.activity.getResources();

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(resource.getString(R.string.NAMESPACE), resource.getString(R.string.METHOD_NAME_Customer));
request.addProperty("phoneID",this.phoneID);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHTTPRequest = new HttpTransportSE(resource.getString(R.string.URL));
// androidHTTPRequest.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
androidHTTPRequest.debug = true;
try
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        androidHTTPRequest.call(resource.getString(R.string.SOAP_ACTION_Customer), envelope);
        webResult = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        if(webResult != null)
            break;      
    }

}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return webResult;
```

what should be done extra for local server to receive parameter??

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: is your probleme solved?

Comment: Yes, actually I was using ip address as URL, which was not supposed to be there, Only thing needs to be changed is putting ip address before .asmx line, i.e mine was.. URL = www.someaddress.com/ AND NAME_SPACE = www.someaddress.com/webservice.asmx, so now changed only name_space to ip/webservice.asmx and values got passed successfully